# Mysql select query - stuck in where condition

Tags: mysql, select

I have 2 tables:

```
Users:
------------------------------
id | name
--------------------------
 1 | John
 2 | Dane
 3 | Foo
 4 | Bar

 Matches Table:
----------------------------
 id | userid1 | userid2
----------------------------
  1 |    1    |   3
  2 |    2    |   4
```

**Question:**
From the matches table with id 1, i want to fetch John and Foo in one query. How can i do that ?

I already have one solution but its dull. That is selecting records from matchs tables and then while looping, trigger queries for getting names. .

Comment: Just join the table twice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a `JOIN`...

```
SELECT u1.*, u2.*
FROM Matches m
    JOIN Users u1 ON u1.id = m.userid1
    JOIN Users u2 ON u2.id = m.userid2
WHERE m.id = [ YOUR DESIRED USER ID (for example: 1) ]
```

Comment: This works. Just a question. Shouldn't i be using inner join ? Because i am sure of the fact that the data exist in both the tables.

Comment: @AbhishekSaha Yes, you're 100% correct. But, in most SQL dialects, if you want to do an INNER JOIN, you can omit the "INNER" part and just write "JOIN". "INNER JOIN" and "JOIN" are the same thing, it's just a matter of coding style (readability vs. brevity)...

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. Ticking your answer.

Comment: @AbhishekSaha Also, the same goes for OUTER JOINs. You don't have to write the word "OUTER" in most cases, but you can if you want to. Both "LEFT JOIN" and "LEFT OUTER JOIN" are the same thing. But just "JOIN" by itself implies that it is inner.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT name from Matches, Users where Matches.id = 1 AND (Users.id = Matches.userid1 OR Users.id = Matches.userid2)
```

This should work.